# Ambari 1.7 install can't register host - host entry doesn't exist in database

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to install HDP 2.2 via Ambari 1.7 on a Centos 6.5 node.

I must admit that the installation instructions are a little confusing, but I believe I've done all of the necessary steps for the Ambari installation wizard to work.  The Ambari server setup went fine, I have created a MySQL database for Ambari and ran the create SQL script that generated the schema, etc.

Now, when I try to register the host via the wizard, I get an exception that says my host doesn't exist in the database.  Well, that's true, my hosts table is empty.  My ultimate question is how to get passed this error and continue with the installation.  But I believe it might be as simple as needing to run some script that inserts to the ambari db hosts table.  Does anyone know when that table gets written to?

I have updated my hosts file with the fully qualified host name and various other config changes mentioned in the installation guide.

I am completely new to all of this stuff and trying to create a single node PoC - any help would be appreciated.

Here is the log entry:

> 17:31:35,174  INFO [Thread-21] JobStoreTX:861 - Freed 0 triggers from
>   'acquired' / 'blocked' state. 17:31:35,184  INFO [Thread-21]
>   JobStoreTX:871 - Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time
>   of the last shut-down. 17:31:35,184  INFO [Thread-21] JobStoreTX:884 -
>   Recovery complete. 17:31:35,185  INFO [Thread-21] JobStoreTX:891 -
>   Removed 0 'complete' triggers. 17:31:35,185  INFO [Thread-21]
>   JobStoreTX:896 - Removed 0 stale fired job entries. 17:31:35,187  INFO
>   [Thread-21] QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler
>   ExecutionScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
>   **17:32:08,520 ERROR [qtp864571289-20] ActionDBAccessorImpl:241 - Host  doesn't exist in database 17:32:08,588 ERROR
>   [qtp864571289-20] AbstractResourceProvider:280 - Caught
>   AmbariException when creating a resource
>   org.apache.ambari.server.AmbariException: Host 
>   doesn't exist in database
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.actionmanager.ActionDBAccessorImpl.persistActions(ActionDBAccessorImpl.java:242)**
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.orm.AmbariJpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(AmbariJpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:68)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.actionmanager.ActionManager.sendActions(ActionManager.java:96)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.actionmanager.ActionManager.sendActions(ActionManager.java:85)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariManagementControllerImpl.createAction(AmbariManagementControllerImpl.java:3071)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider$1.invoke(RequestResourceProvider.java:121)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider$1.invoke(RequestResourceProvider.java:118)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.AbstractResourceProvider.createResources(AbstractResourceProvider.java:273)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider.createResources(RequestResourceProvider.java:118)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl.createResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:274)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.persistence.PersistenceManagerImpl.create(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:75)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.CreateHandler.persist(CreateHandler.java:36)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.BaseManagementHandler.handleRequest(BaseManagementHandler.java:72)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseRequest.process(BaseRequest.java:135)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:103)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:72)
>           at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.RequestService.createRequests(RequestService.java:137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's late but I had the same error and I solved it opening ports 8440 and 8441 in the ambari-server host.

The usual work flow when ambari-server is creating the agents is as follow:

- Ambari-server host provisions by ssh all ambari-agents
- Every ambari-agent needs to callback to https://ambari-server:8440 and register itself in the server.
- All agents are registered and now you can install "stuff" in them through ambari.

The problem was the agents in different nodes couldn't execute the callback cause they couldn't reach ambari-server url in that port.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried to open the ports using iptables but it is still not working. How do you manage to open the ports on your server.

Comment: I did it from the AWS console. Do you have the exact same error?

Comment: Yes I am having the same issue. however I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I think it is not compatible with Ambari. I am not sure though but this is what is said here. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/30629/ubuntu-1604-compatible-with-ambari.html

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue, we solved it by installing openssl (`yum install openssl` on CentOS/Redhat/Fedora).

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing ticket on ambari-dev that could help you out [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-9088) (Thanks Greg Hill!) with the registration.

Essentially, python 2.7.9 has an incompatible ssl module used by the httpslib to connect to the ambari-server -- validation between agent & server doesn't work. The work around is to force the ambari-agent to use use python 2.6.x by appending this line to /var/lib/ambari-agent/ambari-env.sh

```
 PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6
```

Hope this helps.